# How I can manipulate with more bootstrap models in route/controller on the same page (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have one page with five bootstrap nav-tabs and over ten bootstrap models `(create/edit/delete)`. I'm stuck with `route/controller` because the route is the same and I want to put all in one controller because it is on the same page in application but I can't create more `update/store` function and call only one function in the controller for different models.

I made a custom application in PHP, but now I want to create the same in Laravel, but I'm new with Laravel and I don't know how I can do that and what is an answer on my problem. Thanks

Comment: show your code please

Comment: use request method in controller like if(request("edit") if(request("delete")

Comment: I have no problem specifically with some piece of code, I just don't know how I can do something like that and if it's possible at all. I'll try to explain as close as possible

I have a layout.blade with all modals (10+) and for each, I want to pass a different action in the same controller because is on the same page/url. E.g  ClientController@update1 , ...@update2 / or store/delete function

Routes: 
Route::get('client', 'ClientController@index');
Route::resource('client', 'ClientController');

I hope I explained closer